# C - Passing multiple pointers as parameters to pthread_create

Tags: c, string, pointers, struct

I am new to C and these concepts of pointers are extremely confusing to me. I am trying to do something that seems so simple, but I am getting a lot of compilation errors.

I want to spawn a new thread and pass it multiple pointers as parameters (seems like the only way you can use global variables in c is through pointers), so I created a struct that will hold all these pointers, but it wont seem to compile no matter what I change.

Here is my code (i took out most of the code, except for where my problem seems to be)

```
//want to store the pointers in pointers, so when I change a pointer it changes the "global" variable

void request_handler(params *parameters) {
    params parameter = *parameters;
    int *numberOfOtherServers = parameter.numberOfServers;
    int *clientSock = parameter.clientSock;
    char ***serverList = parameters.serverList;
    struct function **functionList[10] = parameters.functionList[10];
}

typedef struct {
    int *clientSock;
    int *numberOfServers;
    char **serverList;
    struct function *functionList[10];
} params;

struct function {
    char name[20];
    int parameterNumer;
    int canDo;
    char *otherServers[10];

};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int client_sock_desc;

    pthread_t handler_thread;

    struct function functionList[10] = {{"",0, 0, {}}};
    int i =0, numberofOtherServers;
    char *serverList[10];

    //create a struct to pass as the parameters
    struct params parameters;
    parameters.clientSock = &client_sock_desc;
    parameters.functionList[10] = functionList;
    parameters.numberOfServers = &numberofOtherServers;
    parameters.serverList = serverList;

    //create a thread for the new clients request to be handled
    if(pthread_create(&handler_thread, NULL, request_handler, parameters) != 0) {
        perror("pthread_create failed");
    }
}
```

C is by far the messiest language if ever used. This task should be so simple, yet I'm so lost because of the guessing of how many * or & i should put on a variable just to call it.

Comment: "(seems like the only way you can use global variables in c is through pointers)" - ***???***

Comment: yes. i dont know how to change variables i declared in main in the function request_handler

Comment: from what i have read so far, C doesnt have global scope variables

Comment: @userXXX You can have file-scope variables, and variables with even wider scope (`extern int errno;` just to cite and example).

Comment: ah i see, i just googled that right now. but if i still wanted to do it through pointers, what am I doing wrong? I seem to be getting a lot of errors, first being it is saying 'params' is an unknown type. I thought using the typedef keyword for a struct will change that?

Comment: Passing a pointer to the variable doesn't make it global.  You were passing a pointer to a function-scope variable, which results in undefined behaviour (as the variable is almost certainly off the stack by the time it's used in the other thread).

Comment: i want to pass a pointer (of a variable defined in main function) to a function-scoped variable so whenever I change that function-scoped variable the same variable in main. If this is not the correct way to do it, can you please tell me how.

Comment: @user2158382: you might like to solve your issues the old fashion style: Don't google snippets, but read all. The latter could be done using this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language

Answer (score 1):

You should pass address of `parameters` to `request_handler` function through `pthread_create`. But as it is a local variable, its not appropriate to pass its address.

So define it as pointer and allocate memory to it.

```
struct params *parameters = malloc(sizeof(*parameters));
```

Set members appropriately using `->`, and pass it as it is.

Update: few more errors

- Move definition of `params` at the top, before `request_handler` function.
- In main define `parameters` a `params *parameters` not `struct params *parameters`
- Use `parameters->` to access members instead of `parameters.` wherever it is pointer.

Comment: Why are you suggesting that it's necessary to give the struct a name?  That's not relevant to the question.

Comment: i am still getting an error in the parameter of request_handler(). it says 'params' is an unknown type.

Comment: even after changing the definition of that params struct, I am still getting an error saying unknown type name 'params'.

Comment: ah that fixed a lot of build errors, but the last one I am getting is. "Array initializer must be an initializer list" for this line
struct function **functionList[10] = parameters->functionList[10];

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do there, but syntactically that line should be `struct function *functionList[10] = parameters.functionList;`. Also, move structure definition of `function` before `params` definition.

Comment: I made your changes and the code compiles fine, but it still does not do what I need it to do. I am just trying to pass over pointers to the function request_handler, so whenever I change those actual values (i.e, add a new string to the array of string called "serverList" in request_handler) it will actually also add that new string to "serverList" in the main function